# Fetch Senders name from contacts and the time & date of message arrival in my app

Tags: android, contacts, smsmanager

I am building a inbox sort of app that fetches all the messages from inbox and shows it in a listview of my app. I am facing difficulty in fetching the senders name in the listview, it only shows the number of the sender.  Please help.

public class SMSListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter
{

```
private Context mContext;
Cursor cursor;
public SMSListAdapter(Context context,Cursor cur)
{
        super();
        mContext=context;
        cursor=cur;

}

public int getCount()
{
    // return the number of records in cursor
    return cursor.getCount();
}

// getView method is called for each item of ListView


public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

// getView method is called for each item of ListView

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // inflate the layout for each item of listView
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_each_item, null);

    // move the cursor to required position
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
   // contact name


    // fetch the sender number and sms body from cursor
    String senderNumber=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));       
    String smsBody=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));

    //long timeMillis = cursor.getColumnIndex("date");
    //Date date = new Date();
    //SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    //String dateText = format.format(date);
    //15022014

   // String senderName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));

    // get the reference of textViews
    TextView textViewConatctNumber=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSMSSender);
    TextView textViewSMSBody=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageBody);
    TextView textViewDate=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    //15022014
   // TextView textViewSMSName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSMSName);


    // Set the Sender number and smsBody to respective TextViews
    textViewConatctNumber.setText(senderNumber);
    textViewSMSBody.setText(smsBody);
    textViewDate.setText(dateText);
   //15022014
   // textViewSMSName.setText(name);

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
// display name
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME))
```

Finding all Data of a given type for a given contact

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
      new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
      Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
              + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
      new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
```

read more details about Insert, Update, Delete and Query operations from [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html)